# Как правильно отсортировать файлы

Tags: java, файлы, сортировка

Хочу отсортировать фолдеры по лексикографическому порядку (алфавитному), но возникает ошибка в коде ниже:

> Bad return type in lambda expression: boolean cannot be converted to int

```
File file = new File(path.toString());
File[] filesAndFolders = file.listFiles();
Arrays.stream(filesAndFolders)
    .sorted((f1, f2) -> f1.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(f2.toString()));
```

Буду рад помощи, `Path` - любой путь в системе.

Comment: используйте `compareTo` вместо `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: лучше будет `f1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(f2.getName().toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, сортировка выполняется не по методу `equals`/`equalsIgnoreCase`, для неё используется либо метод `Comparable::compareTo` либо `Comparator::compare(T a, T b)`.

Во-вторых, в данном случае сортировка при помощи стрима будет безрезультатна, так как не вызывается ни одна терминальная операция (`Stream::sorted` - промежуточная (intermediate) операция), следует использовать [`Arrays::sort(T[], Comparator<?> super T) c`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-)

```java
Arrays.sort(filesAndFolders, Comparator.comparing(f -> f.toString().toLowerCase()));
```

или

```java
Arrays.sort(filesAndFolders, (f1, f2) -> 
    f1.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(f2.toString())
);
```